# After debian downgrade all packages are in local or obsolete

Tags: linux, debian, debian-wheezy, apt, downgrade

I have weird problem: because, after downgrading from Debian jessie (testing) to wheezy (stable) - by changing sources.lost.
Apt-get don't want to downgrade packages, but they are in Installed (local or obsolete).

Of course I can do it manually: I can force version on every package, but it will take a long time.

PS I am using Raspberry Pi